# Как прочитать имя excel файла в Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Имеется папка с файлами excel, нужно узнать полные имена всех этих файлов.

Comment: http://delphibasics.ru/FindFirst.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Познакомьтесь с функциями [FindFirst](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/faq_delphi_basics/FindFirst.php.html) и [FindNext](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/faq_delphi_basics/FindNext.php.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure ListFileDir(Path: string; FileList: TStrings);
var
 SR: TSearchRec;
 begin
 m:=0;
   if FindFirst(Path + '*.*', faAnyFile, SR) = 0 then
    begin
     repeat
       if (SR.Attr <> faDirectory) then
       begin
         ar[m]:=SR.Name;
         st[m]:=ar[m];
         l:=Length(ar[m]);
         Delete(st[m], l-3, 4);
         FileList.Add(st[m]);
         m:=m+1;
       end;
     until FindNext(SR) <> 0;
     FindClose(SR);
   end;
end;
```